# PHP- unable to execute `ssh-add -l`

Tags: php

I am unable to execute ssh-add through php

```
$res=`ssh-add -l`;
echo $res;
```

But $res is an empty string. Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: *But all i get is a blank*, do you mean `$res` is an empty string?

Comment: @Moontails: Your question is indeed very clear. Firstly did you keep ` instead of  ' (or " ) deliberately.Or is that a typo?Another thing for executing, we don't use echo, we use exec.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw ` (backtick) is used to execute the command like exec!

Comment: @alex yeah $res is an empty string.

Comment: @ritesh_nitw: It seems like you don't understand the use of backticks in PHP!

Comment: @ritesh_nitw PHP will attempt to execute the contents of the backticks as a shell command; the output will be returned (i.e., it won't simply be dumped to output; it can be assigned to a variable) from the PHP Manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution to this peculiar problem.

I was initially doing

```
$res1=`eval \`ssh-agent\``;
$res2=`ssh-add -l`;
```

However for some reason PHP doesnt seem to able to do this individually so instead i combined them into a single command as

```
$res=`eval \`ssh-agent\`; ssh-add -l`;
```

and Voila! it worked like a charm. I guess these two needed to be binded together.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path to ssh-add (like `/usr/bin/ssh-add`).

Also, make sure `www-data` (or any other user that invokes the PHP process) has the rights to start the process.

Comment: Could you enable PHP [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and check if there's any (error) output?